# Making a <div> overlay in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I'm using the following code to make a `div` overlay.
If the links "login" or "register" are pressed then the `div id="overlay"` covers the page. The code uses jQuery.

It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but it does not work in IE6.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/development-bundle/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <title> </title>
</head>
<style>
    #overlay
    {
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        background: #CCCCCC;
        z-index:100;
    }

    #log_in
    {
        height:25px;
        width:130px;
        float:right;
        color:#00000;
        line-height:1.7em;
        margin-top:0px;
    }

    .login,.register
    {
        color: #000000;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.login,.register').click (function() {
                $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast');
            });
            $('#overlay').click(function() {
                $(this).fadeOut('fast');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="overlay" style="display:none; position:absolute"></div>
    <div id="log_in"><a href="#" class="login">Login</a> &brvbar; <a href="#" class="register" >Register </a></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make it easier on yourself: refuse to support IE6 any longer. It is pure evil and not worthy of anyone's attention.

Comment: In the overlay I had written for one of the sites at my work I used a fixed position type with a large height/width.

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific than, _"does not work in IE6"_

Comment: @MarcB Not everyone has a choice about leaving behind older browsers. For some developers, "refusing to support IE6 any longer" means losing their job.

Comment: @mblase75 Good, we don't want developers supporting IE6.  Eventually if everyone refuses to do it, they will have to pay someone to upgrade their browser.  There is absolutely no reason to be using IE6 any longer besides not wanting to spend money on your company's well-being.

Comment: @AustynMahoney You do realize that some people use computers outside of a company, right? That they just have an older machine at home or in their classroom because it's good enough, and they can't justify several hundred dollars for something new? That they might still spend money at the site you're building if only you gave them access to the thing? (That's what it really comes down to -- not "we shouldn't support this browser," but "can we make enough money by supporting this browser to justify developing for it?")

Comment: @mblase75 then use Chrome, or FF, or pen and paper almost anything is better then IE6

Comment: @mblase75 Upgrade.  There is no machine on earth that can run IE6 that can't run a newer version.  Even if you are on XP, MS supports up to IE8 I believe.  According to your scenario, if you can't afford to get a machine that can run something other than IE6, you won't be spending money on a website.  Also, if Google can stop supporting IE6, every other company on Earth can too.

Comment: not to mention Microsoft itself doesn't support it: http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is your problem; overlay not showing, or showing at the wrong place

but try this:
Remove this

```
bottom:0;
right:0;
```

And add this :

```
body{height:100%;width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have a malformed color code around line 28.  #00000 needs another zero.  I don't have IE6 to test.